Generate XSLT containing distinct data, their respective count and sum from XML
The following XML is an example of the items I need help creating an XLST file for this:
     <Information>
      <Healthcare id="HCE6E18AE84E1459C86FC2B325D1DED4E">  
        <Name>Apollo</Name>
        <Price>1000</Price>
      </Healthcare>
      <Healthcare id="HEE31A8489A2A4114AEC9E6E1BAAD9254">
        <Name>Apollo</Name>
        <Price>1500</Price>
      </Healthcare>
      <Healthcare id="H49C5C6E471F04141B3A363EBC189C572">
        <Name>MAX</Name>
        <Price>3200</Price>
      </Healthcare>
      <Healthcare id="HE0B65576216F40CAA2AD3E3C18D6F2B0">
        <Name>Artemis</Name>
        <Price>1200</Price>
      </Healthcare>
      <Healthcare id="H4F888B5234534C05B2C8ADE391B5B2F3">
        <Name>Fortis</Name>
        <Price>1650</Price>
      </Healthcare>
      <Healthcare id="HE450A3325A7A4B6B9DB289F545E6D460">
        <Name>Fortis</Name>
        <Price>4500</Price>
      </Healthcare>
      <Healthcare id="H67DC7579ACC74E609D5E552F6BB70153">
        <Name>Narayana</Name>
        <Price>2200</Price>
      </Healthcare>
    </Information>

I want the output of the XLST to look like the following table:



Name
Count
Total Price




Apollo
2
2500


Max
1
3200


Artemis
1
1200


Fortis
2
6150


Narayana
1
2200




This is a grouping question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 and higher.

Please ask a specific question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

In XSLT 3.0 the essence of the solution is
<xsl:for-each-group select="Healthcare" group-by="Name">
  <tr>
    <td>{current-grouping-key()}</td>
    <td>{count(current-group())}</td>
    <td>{sum(current-group()/Price)}</td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each-group>

